# How to pass data to input through label?

Tags: php, input, label

This is really something I couldn't find anywhere. Or, maybe a different solution for it, but I can't really figure it out.

Let's say I have a `<label for='example'>X</label>`

Now, that I have a `<input id='example' value='//resultfromdb//' type='submit' />`

*Note that **type=submit** here*

The problem is, that I have to store a value in each "input", and by input here I mean label, that is pulled out from database. But binding a label to a input with the same ID won't work as expected. There is only one input, but has to change it's value through form submission regarding to label My expectation is something like

`<label for='example' value='//resultfromdb//'></label>...`

This didn't work obviously... Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

There is **x** amount of labels pulled out from DB, but they must have a different value "Stored" in "themselves", but they are binded to only one input. The input will get the value of label when clicked on the label containing a value. Example:

```
<label for='example' value='1'></label>
<label for='example' value='2'></label>
<label for='example' value='3'></label>
<label for='example' value='4'></label>
<label for='example' value='5'></label>
<label for='example' value='6'></label>

<input type='submit' id='example' value='**the label value**' />
```

Comment: For different `id`s create labels with different `for`. Over.

Comment: And `id` should be __unique__ on a page. So having multiple items with same ids is allowed but not valid.

Comment: You dont understand it. Did you read that data is pulled out of db?

Comment: And did you actually read the updated question?

Comment: Okay, I don't understand what you want. Have a nice day.

Comment: What I want? I want to send data to input value through label. What is hard to understand?

Comment: I think we don't understand what you mean by "send data to input value through label".

Comment: Okay I will briefly explain it in question...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - See my Q now please

Comment: Instead of setting them as `value="xx"` on the labels, set them as `data-value="xx"` and then add an "onclick"-event on the labels. When someone clicks on a label, get the `data-value="xx"` from the clicked label and update the input value.

Comment: ...i would probably use jQuery or Zepto for that, just to make it a bit easier, and update the question with "html", "javascript" tags and remove "php".

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Yeah I'm gonna use jQuery but yet I really don't understand the **data** tool. Can you somehow show me example of it?

Comment: Sure... you can see examples in the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)